# Match and count rows containing numeric characters

Tags: r, iteration, dplyr

I have a dataframe oject  based on a single column containing strings with alphabetic and numeric characters.
I wan to count the number of rows based on the match of numeric character with the grepl function.

In my dummy dataset I have 6 rows containing strings with 3 different sequences  of numeric characters: 1911, 1896 and 1906.
In my real dataset I have 30 different sequences of numeric characters and 30 000 rows.

```
dataset <- c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1911", "consectetur adipiscing elit 1911", "Pellentesque at pellentesque nulla 1906", "Aenean eget feugiat ligula 1906", "Aenean eget feugiat ligula. Fusce vulputate 1911", "dui eget fermentum tristique 1896")
dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)
```

Calculating n rows for "1911" with dplyr

```
library(dplyr) 
dataset2 <-  dataset %>%
 filter(grepl("1911", dataset)) %>%      # filtering with grepl
 summarise (total_1911= length(dataset)) # summarise n rows
```

So I can I make an iteration to avoid to make this command for each numeric character?  ( in base R or dplyr)

my expected output:

```
date    n
1911    3
1906    2
1896    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We extract the numeric part, use that as grouping variable and `summarise` to get the frequency of elements (`n()`)

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>% 
     group_by(date = str_extract(dataset, "\\d+")) %>%
     summarise(n = n())
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
count(dataset, date = paste0("total_", gsub("\\D+", "", dataset)))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#        date     n
#       <chr> <int>
#1 total_1896     1
#2 total_1906     2
#3 total_1911     3
```

Using `gsub` we remove all non-number characters and paste it together with `total_`. We use `count` to get the number of rows per unique date.

Answer (score 2):

In base R, we can do this by extracting all the `unique` numbers from the columns and then finding occurrence of each one in the column using `grepl`.

```
nums <- unique(gsub("[^0-9]", "", dataset$dataset))
sapply(nums, function(x) sum(grepl(x, dataset$dataset)))


# 1911 1906 1896 
#   3    2    1
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we could feed the output of `gsub` to `table`:

```
table(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", dataset$dataset))

1896 1906 1911 
   1    2    3
```

or as a data.frame with variable names added using `setNames`.

```
setNames(data.frame(table(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", dataset$dataset))), c("date", "n"))
  date n
1 1896 1
2 1906 2
3 1911 3
```